# How to set parameters to search in scikit-learn GridSearchCV

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I want to use scikit-learn's GridSearchCV to optimise a BaggingClassifier that uses a support vector classifier (SVC). I want the grid search to search over parameters for both the BaggingClassifier and the SVC.

I have tried this setup:

```
svc_pipe = Pipeline([
     ('svc', SVC(probability=True)),
])
pipe = Pipeline([
     ('bag', BaggingClassifier(svc_pipe, no_estimators=50)),
])

params = {
    'bag__bootstrap_features' : [True, False],
    'bag__svc__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
    'bag__svc__decision_function_shape': ['ovo', 'ovr']
}

rnd_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=params)
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter svc for estimator BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('svc', SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False))]),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=True, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=50, n_jobs=-1, oob_score=False,
         verbose=0, warm_start=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Can someone show me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in `pipe`, `no_estimators` should be `n_estimators`.

To address your problem, if you run the following piece of code:

```
for param in rnd_search.get_params().keys():
    print(param)
```

This will show you how the parameters are passed to different parts of the pipeline, the parameters of interest are:

- `bag__base_estimator__svc__kernel`
- `bag__base_estimator__svc__decision_function_shape`

So you were almost there, you were just missing `base_estimator__` in the `svc` pipeline parameters. All you need to do is change the `svc` parameters like so:

```
params = {
    'bag__bootstrap_features' : [True, False],
    'bag__base_estimator__svc__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
    'bag__base_estimator__svc__decision_function_shape': ['ovo', 'ovr']
}
```